# Realizar comparación de 2 FOR en C#

Tags: c#, sql, bucle-for, bucles

estoy intentando realizar la comparación de 2 datos que se obtienen desde 2 bucles FOR.
Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias.

AQUI MI CODIGO:

```
try
            {
                CN_Guias guias = new CN_Guias();
                DateTime Hoy = DateTime.Today;
                string fecha_actual = Hoy.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                string mes, año;
                mes = txt_mes.Text;
                año = txt_anno.Text;
                string ruta = @"" + txt_ruta.Text + año + mes + "";
                String[] dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(ruta);
                int cantidad_imagen_db = guias.Listar_Guias_xMes_xAño(mes, año).Rows.Count;
                //MessageBox.Show(cantidad_imagen_db.ToString());
                //(Convert.ToInt32(mes), Convert.ToInt32(año)).Rows.Count;
                //INICIO FOR
                for (int o = 0; o < cantidad_imagen_db; o++) //Recorre la cantidad de Imagenes de la DB
                {
                    string nom_imagen_db = guias.Listar_Guias_xMes_xAño(mes, año).Rows[o][0].ToString();
                    //MessageBox.Show(nom_imagen_db);

                    //INICIO FOR
                    for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++)
                    {
                        string nom_img = dirs[i];
                        string cadenaTexto = nom_img;
                        String[] resultado = cadenaTexto.Split('\\');
                        string ima_guia = resultado[resultado.Length - 1];
                        string cadenaTexto2 = ima_guia;
                        String[] resultado2 = cadenaTexto2.Split('.');
                        string ima_guia2 = resultado2[resultado2.Length - 2];
                        //MessageBox.Show(ima_guia2);
                    //VALIDAR INGUALDAD DE NOMBRES
                        if (nom_imagen_db == ima_guia2) //-------> AQUI COMPARO LOS NOMBRES(SI FUNCIONA) PERO EL TEMA ES EN LA LINEA DE ABAJO
                        { //IF EL NOMBRE DE LA BASE DE DATOS ES  IGUAL A LA QUE RECORRE EL OTRO FOR(NO REALIZAR NADA)
                        //PERO SI NO COINDICE --> QUE HAGA LO DE ABAJO
                        MessageBox.Show("OK"); }
                        else {
                        //LA IDEA ES QUE LLAME A UNA FUNCIÓN DE INSERCIÓN -> PARA REGISTRAR QUE NO TIENE IMAGEN
                        // EL PROBLEMA ES QUE EL FOR RECORRE Y VALIDA CON CADA UNA DE ELLA
                        // EJEMPLO: SI EN LA DB TENGO EL DATO "IMAGEN-0001" Y EN EL FOR(IMAGEN-0001)--> NO REALIZARA NADA
                        // PERO DENTRO DEL FOR HABRA MAS DATOS CON LOS QUE VALIDARA -> ESO SIGNIFICA REALIZARA VARIAS INSERCIONES EN LA DB.
                        //COMO PUEDO SOLUCIONAR ESO, PARA QUE SOLO INSERTE 1 VEZ CUANDO NO ENCUENTRE EL DATO
                //*************************************************************************
                //TABLA-DB     | FOR QUE OBTIENE NOMBRES DE IMAGEN DE UNA CARPETA
                ___________________________________________________________________________
                //IMAGEN-0001 | IMAGEN-0001
                              | IMAGEN-0002
                              | IMAGEN-....
                //*************************************************************************
                //CON ESO HARIA QUE EL DATO DE LA TABLA-DB IMAGEN-001 BUSQUE SU IGUALDAD EN EL FOR,
                //ESTO SUELE SER ALEATORIO, ASI QUE PUEDE IR COMPARANDO 
                //IF(IMAGEN-0001 = IMAGEN-0002){"NO TIENE"}--->PERO ACA ESTARIA REALIZANDO EL REGISTRO EN LA BASE DE DATOS -ERROR!!!!
                //IF(IMAGEN-0001 = IMAGEN-0001){"SI TIENE"}

                 MessageBox.Show("NO TIENE IMAGEN"); }
            }
            //FIN FOR
        }
        //FIN FOR
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias editar la pregunta y publicar el codigo de forma identada? porque asi como esta no se entiende nada. Ademas explicate un poco mas completo que es lo que intentas comparar

Comment: En resumidas cuentas: lo que quiero realizar es registrar en una tabla(insert detalle) cuando un dato de mi tabla no tiene imagen. Uno de mis datos(campo de una tabla en SqlServer que contiene el mismo nombre puede estar en un array)se busca en un array que es recorrido por un for en cual contiene nombres de muchas imágenes. Ahí es cuando válida el nombre, si es que no lo encuentra que haga algo(insert). Eso es lo requiero. ¿Se logra entender?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tu problema es solo un tema de lógica...

Vos tenes dos listas, y queres comparar si en una esta la otra o no...

O sea, para simplificar usemos tu codigo, aunque mostrar tu error en el medio del codigo lo único que hace es que sea confuso.

```
for (int o = 0; o < cantidad_imagen_db; o++) //Recorre la cantidad de Imagenes de la DB
{
    string nom_imagen_db = guias.Listar_Guias_xMes_xAño(mes, año).Rows[o][0].ToString();
    bool ExisteImagen = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++)
    {
        string nom_img = dirs[i];
        ...
        string ima_guia2 = resultado2[resultado2.Length - 2];
        if (nom_imagen_db == ima_guia2)
        { 
            ExisteImagen = true;
        }
    }
    If (!ExisteImagen)
    {
        INSERTARREGISTRO();
    }
}
```

Para que se entienda, lo que hice fue simplificar tu problema. Hago la comparacion pensando que no existe una igualdad. Si existe una igualdad, pongo la variable ExisteImagen en true. 
Cuando termina el for, verifico si existe la imagen, y si no existe (o sea que ExisteImagen sigue siendo false, como la puse antes del for) inserto el registro.

Comment: Muchas gracias **@gbianchi**